# Passing a ViewBag to Listboxfor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

On my view I want to show a CheckBoxList that will show the names of all the students. Checking each student will ultimately mark their attendence. What I want to do is pass a ViewBag that (supposedly) contains a SelectList of students.

Here is what I am trying to do in Controller.

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var @class = db.Classes.Find(id);
        var students = @class.Students.ToList();
        foreach (Student student in students)
        {
            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = student.St_name,
                Value = student.St_id.ToString(),
                Selected = student.IsSelected
            };
            selectListItems.Add(item);
        }
        ViewBag.students = selectListItems;
        var timetables = @class.Timetables.ToList();
        ViewBag.Sat_ti_fk_id = new SelectList(timetables, "Ti_id", "Ti_day");
        return View();
    }
```

And this is what I am doing in my View

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sat_st_fk_id, "Sat_st_fk_id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(ViewBag.students, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sat_st_fk_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

But the ListBoxFor method is showing error that says it takes 2 arguments.
Any sort of help is apreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: can you remove this `htmlAttributes:` and try

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.ListBoxFor` Takes three arguments

1. The property that value are stored in
2. List of data to show as *SelectList*
3. Html attributes ( *optional* )

You should change the `@Html.ListBoxFor` to this

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Sat_st_fk_id, ViewBag.students as SelectList, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. But my listbox is empty now even. I'll see what the problem is.

Comment: @razaabbas Do you want show `students` list or `Sat_ti_fk_id `?

Comment: I needed to pass student list it was stored in viewbag of the name Sat_ti_fk_id. I figured out the problem, all is good now thanks to you.